# Using match.call() in recursive function

Tags: r, function

I would like to have a recursive function with a numeric argument.
The general structure is as follows. I added the `is.numeric()` check because my original function is breaking on an operation that requires `AP` to be numeric. My original function will also not create an infinite loop but exit cleanly if no recursion is needed (given by condition1, condition2, ...).

```
myfun <- function(AP, condition1=TRUE, condition2=FALSE){
  # catch the function call
  fun_call <- match.call()
  print(fun_call$AP)
  if(!is.numeric(AP)){stop("Debug stop")}
  myfun(fun_call$AP)
}
```

I would expect this function to go on forever but it breaks because fun_call$AP is no longer numeric.

```
myfun(3)
[1] 3
fun_call$AP
fun_call$AP
 Error in myfun(fun_call$AP) : Debug stop
```

This is probably because I am *not* parsing the arguments properly, how is the way one is supposed to get the arguments when using `match.call()` or is there another way to do it without using `match.call()`?